Conditional Independence , decomposing conditionally dependent events
Problem
A box contains two coins: a regular coin and one fake two-headed coin (P(H) = 1). I
choose a coin at random and toss it twice. Define the following events.
A= First coin toss results in an H.
B= Second coin toss results in an H.
C= Coin 1 (regular) has been selected.
THis is the Scenario of two events that are NOT independent but are conditionally independent, given an event C.
we use the law of total
probability:
$$P(A) = P(A|C)P(C) + P(A|\overline{C})P(\overline{C})$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) 
= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} 
= \frac{3}{4}$$
Similarly, for $P(B)$:
\begin{align*}
P(B) &= P(B|C)P(C) + P(B|C')P(C') \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
Calculating $P(A \cap B)$:
\begin{align*}
P(A \cap B) &= P(A \cap B|C)P(C) + P(A \cap B|C')P(C') \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{5}{8}
\end{align*}
Question
I understand that if A and B are conditionally independent given C, then we can decompose their joint probability as:
$$P(A \cap B|C) = P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C)$$
However, in the case where we have a biased coin  $C^{c}$ , A and B are no longer independent. If we know that A (the first toss) is a head, then B (the second toss) is certainly a head too, due to the nature of the biased coin. This clearly indicates that A and B are dependent.
Despite this, it seems that the equation:
$$P(A \cap B | C^{c}) = P(A | C^{c}) \cdot P(B | C^{c})$$
is still being used.
My question is: How can we justify using this equation if $A$, $B$, and $C^{c}$ are dependent?

Any two events of probability $1$ are independent of each other. Your "However, in the case where we have a biased coin  $C^{c}$ , $A$ and $B$ are no longer independent. If we know that $A$ (the first toss) is a head, then $B$ (the second toss) is certainly a head too, due to the nature of the biased coin. This clearly indicates that $A$ and B are dependent." is incorrect: if you know you have the two-headed coin, then seeing the result of the first toss does not change the probability of the result of the second toss.

You said "Any two events of probability 1
are independent of each other."  Take the same question but now for a biased coin P(H)=0.75 for heads and P(T)=0.25 for tails.  Now A and B are not independent given C′ ?
To calculate P(A ∩ B ∣ C′ ):  we do something like this?
P(A ∩ B ∣ C′) =  P( A ∣ C′) ⋅P(B ∣ A , C′)
law of total probability to calculate P(A ∩ B) :
P(A ∩ B) =  P( A ∣ C′) ⋅ P(B ∣ A , C′)   + P( A ∣ C) P( B ∣ C)

You can say $P(A \cap B) = P( C′)P( A \mid C′)  P(B \mid A , C′) + P( C)P( A \mid C) P( B \mid A,C)$

You expanded using the chain rule for both the biased coin and the regular coin. However, shouldn't the dependency only be considered for the biased coin (P(H) = 0.75), while the regular coin should be treated as independent?
something like this maybe?
$P(A \cap B) = P(C')P(A \mid C')P(B \mid A,C') + P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C)P(C)$

My second comment was general. Here $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$ or given $C'$ so $P(A \cap B) = P( C′)P( A \mid C′)  P(B \mid C′) + P( C)P( A \mid C) P( B \mid C)$.  If $C'$ is the event of a double headed coin then $P(B \mid A, C') =1 = P(B \mid C')$ and $P(A \cap B \mid C')=1=P( A \mid C′)  P(B \mid C′)$ so you still have conditional independence.
